# OData CRM query: Any open opportunities with a given target?

Tags: javascript, odata, crm, dynamics-crm-2016, data-integrity

Our organization has a CRM installation on which we've done extensive customization. Right now I'm trying to implement a solution to enforce a business rule: Prevent users from updating a program to inactive when the program is a designation opportunity on an open opportunity.

[image]

I know how to prevent the update; return `false` from `OnSave()` in the JavaScript. I haven't been able to find out when that's the case. The best idea I've come up with is to make a SOAP call to the OData endpoint in CRM, but I've come across a sticking point at the last step. (If you've got a better idea I'm totally open to it.)

Here's what I've got. I can get the program in question:
`programset(guid'thisone')`
<sup><sub>.../OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F4D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-
C4346BACAAC0')</sub></sup>

I can get the associated designations:
`programset(guid'thisone')/program-desig`
<sup><sub>.../OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F0D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-C4346BACAAC0')/uwkc_uwkc_program_uwkc_opportunitydesignation</sub></sup>

and the associated Opportunities to those:
`programset(guid'thisone')/program-desig?$expand=desig-opportunity`
<sup><sub>...OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F0D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-C4346BACAAC0')/uwkc_uwkc_program_uwkc_opportunitydesignation?$expand=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation</sub></sup>

... but now I get a little stuck.

I can filter on a primitive value on the Opportunity (link + field)
`...$filter=opp-oppdesig/EstimatedCloseDate gt DateTime('2016-07-01')`
<sup><sub>...OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F0D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-C4346BACAAC0')/uwkc_uwkc_program_uwkc_opportunitydesignation?$expand=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation&$filter=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation/EstimatedCloseDate%20gt%20DateTime%272016-07-01%27</sub></sup>

and I can filter on a complex value on the Designation (field + value)
`...$filter=statecode/Value gt 0`
<sup><sub>...OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F0D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-C4346BACAAC0')/uwkc_uwkc_program_uwkc_opportunitydesignation?$expand=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation&$filter=statecode/Value%20gt%200</sub></sup>

but I can't make a filter work on a complex value on the Opportunity (connection + field + value) 
`...$filter=opp-oppdesig/statecode/Value gt 0`
<sup><sub>...OrganizationData.svc/uwkc_programSet(guid'F0D75E9D-3A79-E611-80DA-C4346BACAAC0')/uwkc_uwkc_program_uwkc_opportunitydesignation?$expand=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation&$filter=uwkc_opportunity_uwkc_opportunitydesignation/statecode/Value%20gt%200</sub></sup>

> No property 'statecode' exists in type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' at
>   position 45.

How can I filter on the state of an entity two away from what I'm looking at? Or, if there's a better way, what's the best way to prevent in-use programs from being deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

First issue is that you should be using the schema name of the attribute (`StateCode`), and not the logical name (`statecode`).

However, I believe it will then just return another error message:

```
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>-2147220989</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">attributeName</message>
</error>
```

For some reason, it seems that filtering on complex types in an expanded entity does not work properly for the SOAP endpoint. And from what I have tested, the new Web API does not support this kind of depth in a query either yet.

One solution to your problem is to just fetch all the results, and then perform the filtering manually in your code. This of course works best if you can assume that there are not too many related entities retrieved in this kind of query. Also be sure to use `$select` to retrieve only the necessary attributes, as it greatly reduces the time it takes for a query to finish.

Another solution is to perform the query using FetchXML instead. This can be done either via the [Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt607533.aspx), or as a SOAP request you construct yourself.

A third solution is to split your query into multiple queries, so you don't have to filter on a state two entities away in a query.